# Как найти координаты окружности данного радиуса, включающей наибольшее число точек?

Tags: алгоритм

Дано: набор точек с целыми положительными координатами и целый радиус круга. Нужно найти координаты центра круга, в который помещается наибольшее число точек.

Наивная реализация понятна - считать расстояние от каждой точки до каждой, смотреть, какие впишутся в круг и считать те, которые подходят. Но это алгоритмически самое медленное решение.

Хотелось бы узнать алгоритм, который работает быстрее и его сложность.

Comment: Вообще не понимаю, зачем тебе расстояние от каждой точки до каждой.

Comment: А сколько точек? И вообще, окружность или круг? Почему в заголовке одно, а в тексте - другое?

Comment: За куб от числа точек - сравнительно простое решение.

Comment: За квадрат - довольное сложное решение.

Comment: Чисто интуитивно кажется, что если разбить всё это на квадратики (нарисовать сеточку) и считать число точек в квадратиках, то это как-то поможет. Но как именно - сразу не могу сообразить.

Comment: @CrazyElf, если расположить точки на окружности данного радиуса и пошевелить, то задача сделается очень сложной. Хотя можно попользоваться целочисленностью всего чтобы упростить её для небольших радиусов.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy а где почитать про эти решения? Желательно, на русском. Если на русском нет, но и на английском худо-бедно пойдет.

Comment: Смотрите ответ. В нём не используется целочисленность координат. Ещё тут люди пытаются: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151162/find-the-most-points-enclosed-in-a-fixed-size-circle.

Comment: В ответе полный обзор существующих подходов. Это сложная и объемная тема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Два метода разобраны тут, с картинками: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/angular-sweep-maximum-points-can-enclosed-circle-given-radius/.

### Решение за куб от числа точек

Пусть мы нашли круг решающий задачу. Если на его границе нет точек множества, сдвинем его пока хотя бы одна точка на границу не попадёт. Затем будем вращать его пока вторая точка не попадёт на границу.

То есть, если у нас решение, то есть и решение в котором две точки лежат на границе круга. (Разберите сами случай когда в круге только одна точка).

Будем искать лучший круг среди всех кругов с двумя точками на границе. Две точки и радиус определяют не более двух кругов. Всего таких кругов не более `O(NN)`. Для каждого круга сосчитаем сколько других точек в него попало (за `N`). Выберем круг с максимальным числом точек внутри.

За `N^3` отыскивается наилучший круг.

### Решение за квадрат от числа точек (почти)

Вокруг каждой точки исходного множества построим окружность. Эти окружности пересекаются. Построим граф, в котором вершины - все точки пересечения окружностей, ребра - кусочки окружностей. Граф планарный, число ребер и вершин не более `O(N^2)`.

Если взять две окружности с центрами в одной грани графа, то они будут содержать один и тот же набор точек исходного множества. (Остановитесь и подумайте почему это так). Число граней `O(N^2)`.

Если две грани - соседи через дугу окружности, то в них множества точек отличаются на одну точку - ту точку которая нарисовала эту дугу. (Снова остановка для размышлений).

Возьмём любую грань и подсчитаем для неё содержащиеся точки (за `N`). Запустим поиск в ширину по графу (двойственному графу) - перескакиваем через дугу, обновляем счётчик точек (за константу). Весь обход займёт `N^2` - по числу граней. В конце обхода в каждой грани мы знаем сколько точек покрыто окружностью с центром в этой грани.

Для построения графа применяется вариант [алгоритма Бентли-Оттмана](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0). Он построит граф за `N^2logN`. Разметить граф можно за `N^2`.

### Ещё один `NNlogN`

Выберем любую точку множества. Нарисуем полуокружность с началом в этой точке. Полуокружность можно вращать вокруг этой точки. Во время вращения она задевает некоторые другие точки. Каждый момент задевания сохраним как событие. Ещё один набор событий создадим для второй полуокружности. Круговое заметание позволит сосчитать число точек внутри вращающейся окружности. Весь процесс для одной точки займёт `NlogN` - сортировка событий по углу.

Таких заметаний надо сделать `N`. Общая сложность алгоритма `NNlogN`.

Чтобы разобраться вам нужно хорошо понимать что такое заметание.
Идея украдена отсюда: https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-algorithm-for-enclosing-the-maximum-number-of-points-in-a-2-D-plane-with-a-fixed-radius-circle

В целом алгоритм с заметанием должен быть проще предыдущего.

### `N^2`

Предыдущих алгоритм может быть ускорен до `N^2` за счёт штуки под названием "упорядочение". Сложно.

Ещё один подход у Чазелле: [CirclePlacement.pdf](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Echazelle/pubs/CirclePlacement.pdf). Это классик, ему можно верить. Скорее всего решений быстрее квадрата нет и не будет.

**P.S.** Это действительно сложно. Не торопитесь, рисуйте картинки, задавайте вопросы. По объёму - курсовая на старших курсах.